# How to use html select as a navigation

Tags: html, css

how do you use the select tag in html as a navigation?

```
<select>
    <a><option></option></a>
</select
```

I have tried putting the a tag outside the option tag but it still won't work
Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#technical_summary - **Permitted content** : Zero or more `<option>` or `<optgroup>` elements.

Comment: You can not put a link into a select field. If you really want to do this (you rather shouldn't - usability of something like this is rather bad), you'll need to do it using JavaScript.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419682/how-can-i-navigate-to-urls-with-select, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938341/creating-drop-menu-navigation-with-select, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002856/navigate-to-a-page-with-selection-on-dropdown-menu-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

###### Hi @Ivan,

You cannot use the  tag inside a  element in HTML.

You can use switch statement in **JavaScript** with `window.location = "your link"` to achieve that kind of functionality

First create your selection tag with the **ID** and add event on that tag like this `<select name="cars" id="cars" onChange="SelectRedirect()"></select>`
now use **JavaScript** to achieve that. I'm using switch statement.

```js
function SelectRedirect() {
        switch (document.getElementById("cars").value) {
          case "volvo":
            window.location = "page";
            break;

          case "saab":
            window.location = "login";
            break;

          default:
            window.location = "../";
            break;
        }
      }
```

```html
<div>
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
    <select name="cars" id="cars" onChange="SelectRedirect()">
      <option value="volvo">volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The another way you can do that with **onchange** event.

```html
<select onchange="window.location = this.value;">
  <option value="">Your page</option>
  <option value="page1.html">Page 1</option>
  <option value="page2.html">Page 2</option>
  <option value="page3.html">Page 3</option>
</select>
```